# What's wrong with wait() and notify() in the following code in Java?

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization

```
void waitForSignal() {
    Object obj = new Object();
    synchronized(Thread.currentThread()) {
        obj.wait();
        obj.notify();
    }

}
```

I know that it may throw an InterruptedException, does it has other problems? such as dead lock...

Comment: How will it ever wake up?

Comment: It'll throw an `IllegalMonitorStateException` because you're not synchronizing on `obj`.

Comment: Synchronizing on the current thread is completely and utterly pointless. The only thread you are protecting yourself against is your own. You need to synchronize on the *object*.

Answer (score 0):

1. It will not compile because of InterruptedException is not handled
2. If handled, it will throw java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException as mentioned in comments.
3. Yes it is having deadlock issue.
   Every time you are creating a new object inside this method and waiting on  the same object, it will not come out of wait as no other thread have same obj instance, hence will not be able to notify.

Comment: If `obj` is outside the `waitForSignal()` method, and `synchronized(Thread.currentThread())` is set to `synchronized(obj)`, does it still cause deadlock for each thread will call wait() first?

Comment: Yes it will cause deadlock again.
Actually your code does not run properly till it does not come out of wait. Other thread can only call notify when it has obj lock which is not possible as already a thread calling obj.wait has acquired the same